# How to run a test with distribution of load

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I am new to JMeter and need your help with a problem.
I have 4 test scenarios and I need to run it with 30 users load with distribution as 30,10,30,30 percent. Out of 4 scenarios, 1 scenario create a customer ID and that ID is being used in the rest of the scenarios.TO test this, I have created a test data of customer ID's with my 1 scenarios and saved in a CSV file. Now my question is when I will run my test how would I handle the customer iD's generated at the run time and how to manage it with my test data which I have already created. Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With regards to reusing the data, generated in the runtime - you can extract the required data, i.e. customer ID using suitable [JMeter Post-Processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) and store it into a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html). Once done the variable can be re-used in other scenarios. The process is known as [correlation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start) and there is a lot of information on implementation with examples over the web.

With regards to the distribution there are different approaches as well:

- [Throughput Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Throughput_Controller)
- [Switch Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Switch_Controller)
- [Weighted Switch Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeters-weighted-switch-controller-the-ultimate-guide/)

With regards to "manage test data you created" - you can read the values from a CSV file using [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) or [__CSVRead() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__CSVRead)

Comment: Thanks @Dmitri T, finally someone responded to my query, it really helps. Thanks